# Error while publishing to Azure service fabric cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am getting below error when I am trying to publish service fabric application to Azure cluster.

Is this because of any firewall issue since I am working in the corporate env. If its a firewall issue which port needs to open to resolve this? or is this due to any other issue?

```
WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
    Get-ServiceFabricClusterManifest : Operation canceled.
    At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service 
    Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:159 char:28
    +     $clusterManifestText = Get-ServiceFabricClusterManifest
    +                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [Get-ServiceFabricClusterManifest], FabricTransientException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetClusterManifestErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.GetClusterManifest     
    Finished executing script 'Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1'.
    Time elapsed: 00:00:47.5709554
    The PowerShell script failed to execute.
```

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is just firewall, opening the ports might solve the problem, try opening then and come back here if does not solve the problem:

The main ports used by servce fabric are these:

- `ClientConnectionEndpoint:19000`
- `HttpGatewayEndpoint:19080`
- `HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint:19081`

If you look in your cluster configuration, you will find the list of ports being used, something like this:

```
  <Endpoints>
    <ClientConnectionEndpoint Port="19000" />
    <LeaseDriverEndpoint Port="19001" />
    <ClusterConnectionEndpoint Port="19002" />
    <HttpGatewayEndpoint Port="19080" Protocol="http" />
    <HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint Port="19081" Protocol="http" />
    <ServiceConnectionEndpoint Port="19006" />
    <ApplicationEndpoints StartPort="30001" EndPort="31000" />
  </Endpoints>
```