# Get-ServiceFabricClusterManifest: operation canceled

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-powershell, powershell-cmdlet, service-fabric-on-premises

I have created a standalone unsecured one node cluster.I am trying to do package deployment from powershell.
What i have done so far:

1. In package, in Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1
2. i replaced service fabric sdk reference and included ps1 files needed to deply inside my package itself.
3. I dot sourced those files in Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 like this

   . F:\pkg\Debug\Scripts\New-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage.ps1
   . F:\pkg\Debug\Scripts\Utilities.ps1
   . F:\pkg\Debug\Scripts\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1
   4.Now when i run .\Deploy-FabricApplicatin.ps1 from powershell like this

   .\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 -ApplicationPackagePath 'F:\pkg\Debug' -PublishProfileFile 'f:\pkg\Debug\PublishProfiles\Cloud.xml'
   Now I am getting this error
   [The error message screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlGN6.png)

I tried opening ports but still im getting this error. The error vanishes and im able to deploy after two or three tries...but everytime when i deploy for the first few times after standalone cluster creation. Why is this error is happening and how do i rectify it.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to double check the ports as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52853587/error-while-publishing-to-azure-service-fabric-cluster) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/24100/why-doesnt-my-app-service-fabric-work.html) threads.